# Is it correct? $1^n +2^n +...+(p-1)^n=-1 \pmod p$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

$p$ a prime number, $n\in \mathbb{N} $ and $p-1\mid n$ then $1^n +2^n +...+(p-1)^n=-1 \pmod p$

I'm not sure if my  proof is correct:

Take the group $G=(\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{p},\cdot)$ with the multiplication.
Since $p$ is prime then the order of $G$ is $p-1$.
Then  using $n=k(p-1)$ and $p-1=-1 \pmod p$.
Using the Fermat's Little Theorem $a^{p}=a \pmod p$

$1^n +2^n +...+(p-1)^n=1+1+...+1=p-1=-1 \pmod p$

Is it correct?

Comment: How do you prove $a^n \equiv 1$? Also, $Z_p$ is not a group for multiplication.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: The proof is correct.

Comment: @David Why do I have to prove that?

Comment: Don't you use that fact to write $1 + 1 + \dots + 1$?

Comment: 1 is the Identity element of G, and G is cyclic.

Comment: Are you sure that $Z_p$ is a group for multiplication? What is the inverse of $0$?

Comment: @David $Z^*_p$ is usual defined as the multiplicative group of integers modulo $p$ (without the $0$). $Z_p$ does contain $0$ and is a field.

Comment: @mlainz Yes, the question has been edited since I made the comment.

Comment: If $G = Z_p^{*}$, it's true that $G$ is cyclic, but this fact isn't needed. I still think the proof ought to spell out better (in one line) why $a \in G$ implies $a^n = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

First, we have that $(\mathbb{Z}_p^*,\cdot)$ is a group under multiplication. Thus, if $a\in \mathbb{Z}^*$ such that $p\nmid a$ then $[a]_p\in \mathbb{Z}_p^*$. Therefore $$[a]_p^{\mathrm{o}(\mathbb{Z}_p^*)}=[1]_p\Rightarrow [a]_p^{p-1}=[1]_p\Rightarrow [a^{p-1}]_p=[1]_p\Rightarrow a^{p-1}=1\ \mathrm{mod}p\ \ \ (\dagger)$$
Thus if $p-1\mid n$ there exist $k\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $n=(p-1)k$. Bearing in mind the fact that $$[x]_p\in\mathbb{Z}_p^*,\ \ 1\leq x\leq p-1,$$ and due to $(\dagger)$, we obtain the desired result: $$1^n+2^n+\cdots+(p-1)^n=(1^{p-1})^k+(2^{p-1})^k+\cdots +((p-1)^{p-1})^k=\underbrace{(1+1+\cdots+1)}_{p-1}\mathrm{mod}p=-1\mathrm{mod}p.$$